# Proper use of FindControl() in GridViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've inherited some code, littered with GridView's, and I've noticed the following sorts of references in the `OnItemDataBound` method:

```
Label lblSomething = (Label)e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("lblSomething");
Label lblSomethingElse = (Label)e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("lblSomethingElse");
```

The "issue" is that `lblSomething` and `lblSomethingElse` aren't actually in the same cell, but they both appear to be working correctly anyway. Simplifying a bit:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Online materials available to assign">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblThis" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign" HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblThat" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign" HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSomething" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign" HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSomethingElse" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                        

</Columns>
```

Is this behavior expected? If it doesn't matter what cell I'm using the `FindControl()` with, can I safely/reliably simplify with this instead?

```
Label lblSomething = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSomething");
Label lblSomethingElse = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSomethingElse");
```

If not, is it reliable to just use `Cells[0].FindControl()`?

Should I be worried that the cell mismatch is working only by a happy accident, and that I need to fix these cell indexes ASAP, lest everything break?

Or, am I underestimating the power of `FindControl()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, I've found that the following works perfectly fine.

```
Label lblSomething = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSomething");
Label lblSomethingElse = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSomethingElse");
```

Whether this is "best practice" is beyond me.

Also, I've removed `runat="server"` from the first `TemplateField` in the markup to match the others. It's unnecessary, apparently. (Who knew?)

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Online materials available to assign">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblThis" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign" HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblThat" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign" HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSomething" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign" HeaderStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSomethingElse" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                        

</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label myLabel = e.row.FindControl("myControl") as Label;
if(myLabel !=null)
{
     // Do some work
 }
```

I prefer using as for casting.